# search list of hashtables

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, hashtable, c#-2.0

I have a list of hashtables, where each hashtable look something like this:

```
Success: true/false
field1: some_string
field2: some_string
```

What I need to do is first find out if success = true in any of the hashtables (if not, I will return an error code). If there is one or more hashtables with success=true, I need to return a list containing those hashtables.

Comment: I wanted to use Linq to search the list of hastables. I used: var reponse = lhtResult.Find(r => (bool)r["Success"] == true); Just need to confirm if this is the right way of doing it to avoid pitfalls.

Comment: using response = lhtResult.Find(r => (bool)r["Success"] == true); returns one hashtable even if there are multiple matches. How do I modify to get all matches in the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
 response = lhtResult.FindAll(r => (bool)r["Success"] == true);
```